# Cling retrieving descriptor from subnet

Tags: java, multicast, upnp, subnet, cling

I am trying to use cling upnp to get devices and use in my network. I can find and get the devices which are on same subnet (ex. both devices-client&server- on 10.6.x.x) but when I force one to use for example 196.168.x.x and the other one is still on 10.6.x.x I can find the device but can't get the descriptor from it as expected.

I tried to find how to achieve this but couldn't get any results. Can someone lead me to the right direction? I am new to this, I tried port mapping and multicast receiver without success. I think i need to use multicast ip to get the descriptor but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Upnp device discovery uses subnet multicast, it can only work within the subnet.

Comment: Hmm I see. In my case the server and client finds each other at discovery phase but when client tries to get the descriptor of the server, it can't reach the ip of the server as expected. I think somehow I need to make them communicate through multicast ip but I couldn't understand how to do it